# What does the symbol $\in$ mean?

Tags: notation

I am currently studying discrete mathematics, and I have very little background knowledge, and I was wondering what the symbol "$\in$" means.

The following is where I encountered this symbol:

[image: Vector addition]

Comment: It means  "an element of" .  So, saying that, e.g. $x\in \mathbb R$ just means that "$x$ is an element of $\mathbb R$", i.e. $x$ is a real number.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$, by the way, is the set of ordered pairs of reals — equivalently, it's the plane, or the set of points in the plane. (They're equivalent because of coordinates.)

Answer (score 7):

The symbol
$$
\Huge\in
$$
means "in" and is actually typeset by `\in` to reflect this.

In general, if $A$ is any set (whose elements may be numbers or any other objects), we write $x\in A$ to indicate that $x$ is a member (or an element) of $A$. Now, if $x$ is *not* a member of $A$, then we write $x\not\in A$, and this is typeset by `x\not\in A`.

Answer (score 4):

$\in$ means "is an element of", or more simply, "is in", which is why it is `\in` in LaTeX.
For example:

- "Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$" = Let $x$ be an integer.
- "Let $x \in \{0, 1\}$" = Let $x$ be either $0$ or $1$.

Note, that there is also the notation $\ni$, which means the same thing in the other order. For example, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z} \ni x$.
This is read as "contains", and has LaTeX code `\ni`.